# расчет времени работы в ms sql server

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, sql-server-2017

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]есть таблица

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [timestamp]
      ,[_PREV]
      ,[_VAL]
  FROM [TestDB2].[dbo].[Sheet1$]
```

Необходимо посчитать общее время работы по условиям,
что стоп станка это:

```
SELECT timestamp   
FROM [Sheet1$] 
WHERE _VAL = 0 AND _PREV = 1
```

а старт станка:

```
SELECT timestamp   
FROM [Sheet1$] 
WHERE _VAL = 1 AND _PREV = 0
```

нужно посчитать сумму минут стоп минус старт

Comment: Выбираете старты и стопы (если есть пары записей подряд с одинаковым _VAL). И считаете сумму разностей между timestamp и LAG(timestamp) для стопов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не совсем понятно как мне поможет LAG , учитывая что у меня есть в таблице четкое понимание где становк был включен, а где выключен (по столбцам _PREV  и _VAL) _PREv - предыдущее состояние станка

Comment: o_O Для строки стопа LAG(timestamp) - это соответствующий этой строке старт.

Comment: Это к сожалению будет не всегда верным. Есть подряд идущие стопы (0) Исполбщуя LAG можем нарваться на стоп минус стоп (

Comment: *Есть подряд идущие стопы (0)* Ну я ж вроде русским по белому первым делом написал: "Выбираете старты и стопы (если есть пары записей подряд с одинаковым _VAL)". Т.е. первым делом выбрасываете первый из двух подряд стартов, и соответственно второй из двух подряд стопов. Или, если уже получили _VAL и _PREV, оставляете только записи, где их сумма равна единице, и дополнительно получите ещё и _NEXT, сумма которого с _VAL тоже должна быть единицей.

Comment: Cпасибо, не догнпл сразу